# Do all Fragment onCreateView methods called with FragmentActivity in android?

Tags: android, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I have used `FragmentActivity`, `ViewPagerAdapter` and `Fragment` to build a tab format. There have 3 tabs in my `FragmentActivity`. I am confused whether all the `Fragment` `onCreateView` methods are being called when `FragmentActivity` methods are being called or onCreateView methods are called `onClick` of the tab? I have set 3 breakpoints `onCreateView` methods of all my 3 `Fragments`. During debug I found only first 2 `onCreateView` methods are being called. Please explain why only 2 are being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the ViewPagerAdapter will manage creating fragments and destroying fragments based on the user needs. So if you dont set **mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(NUM_TABS-1)**, the default is 1 (you can refer [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29))

That why it only create the first 2 tabs, when you select tab3 , then it will destroy the fragment of tab1 and create fragment of tab3. for your case if you set ***mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2)*** when you debug, you will see that it call 3 onCreateView methods and won't destroy view of any fragment. Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

They are created and destroyed based on the user needs. If you scroll to get to the second fragment you'll see it is created. It's just an optimization. Do you think an application with for example 8 fragments need to keep the 8 fragments in memory ? It would be a waste of resources.

Comment: Ya I understand. But what is the default behavior. My first 2 fragments are being created during start but not the 3rd. When I click on 2nd tab its calling the 3rd fragment. That's why I become confused.